# Updating app: Adding a new pre-populated table (with 50k records) to an existing db

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I am releasing an update to an already existing app in the Android Market.

**What:**

The existing app has a db. As part of the update, I am adding a new table to that db.

**Problem**:

The new table has pre-populated records (about 50k).

If the records were not so many, I could have handled this logic in `onUpgrade()` of my DatabaseHelper for creating a new table and adding these records.

Could someone please help me out on this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: what is the problem with using onUpgrade()?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. This new table has ~50k records in it. With onUpgrade(), I can create a new table but I cannot populate it with the 50k records on the fly since that would require the app to wait till the they are all written.

Comment: you could create the table with onUpgrade, then do the record insertion in an asynctask somewhere else. or do you need all the records to be present before the user can do anything?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I thought about spawaning an AsyncTask but then again, I need the data before showing the first screen to the user. The user needs the data before the app is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you expose the content through a provider?

As Kevin Qiu commented, you can have an async task creating the data, if you also provide access to this data through a content provider you can subscribe to the content change and be notified when the data is available.

Cheers,
Francisco.

Comment: Thanks Francisco for the suggestion. That's a good point but probably the 2nd best option for me. IF I follow this approach, atleast initially I will need to pull all this data from the server while caching the content locally completes. :(